# why button in view inactive with parent view's controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I am using [swipView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) to make a page scrolling app

according to  its `SwipeViewDataSource` protocol, I make a method

```
 - (UIView *)swipeView:(SwipeView *)swipeView viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

        ContentViewController *contentVC = [[ContentViewController alloc]init];
        view = contentVC.view;
        return view;
}
```

to provide the swipping content

and the `ContentViewController` is simple enough:

It only has this two custom methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 200)];
    [btn setTitle:@"click me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

}
-(void) onClick:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"click detected in contentView controller");
}
```

only added a  button in `viewDidLoad` and the click listen method

when running the app, the button showed, but click on don't fire the `OnClick:` method.

After figuring around, I notice that if I put this method

```
-(void) onClick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"on click detected  main view controller");
}
```

To the view which implements the `SwipeViewDataSource` ie in the "parent" which init the `ContentViewController` that line of debug info will be printed.

It's very weird, to me. I mean why that happens?

Comment: Create strong property of ContentViewController and try

Answer (score 0):

Your contentviewcontroller will be released after returning its view in viewForItemAtIndex delegate method since you are retaining its view only. But you are adding button target to self(contentviewcontroller) which was released already.

Comment: then why the method on the parent view's controller was called?